# Magento Session not working in external page (same domain)

Tags: session, magento

Magento Session in external page (same domain) is not working well, I've checked all the other topics here but any solution it is working.

```
require_once ( "../app/Mage.php" );
umask(0);
Mage::app("default");

Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session"); 


if($session->isLoggedIn()){
    //do it
} else {
    //  Transfer them to a login page
    header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/customer/account/login/");
}
```

I can not get this to work, I have checked all recommendations everywhere and nothing work.

Comment: Are you sure you are on the same domain? Remember, `www.domain.com` does not equal `domain.com`.

Comment: yes sure is in the same domain

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information, after the header() function, there should be another line:

```
exit;
```

for the redirection to work.

(Apparently this belongs more to a comment rather than an answer, but I don't have the privilege to comment everwhere yet.)

Comment: yes, thanks, that's true, exit; missing, but I'm still having the issue with the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these lines instead, they looks similar, but work for me on Magento 1.5.1..

```
require_once ( "../app/Mage.php" );
umask(0);
Mage::app("default"); 
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    //do it
} 
else {
    //  Transfer them to a login page
    header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/customer/account/login/");
}
```

Comment: No, is not working that code. I forgot to mention I'm in ver. 1.6.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you already have a session started, so your attempts to start a magento session and get data from it are failing.
If you look inside Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien, the first thing it does is look to see if the $_SESSION variable is already set and return if it is. You could set your debugger breakpoint there and verify if you aren't sure.
You could close the other session and start the magento session to get your data, or you could get both to share the same session